# Question on token systems example in ethereum whitepaper

Tags: tokens, white-paper

I am novice blockchain developer. I was going through ethereum whitepaper and I am struck on some questions. This is one of them.

I couldnt get my head around the token systems application mentioned in the paper. So its mentioned that ethereum has ability to pay transaction feeds directly in the meta currencies or token currency. I couldnt understand the process exaplained for this.

Any one help me understand this please?

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible as of yet, but their are EIPs in the works (1 being *currency and crypto abstraction*, and 2 being *account abstraction*) that would allow this. It would really be up to the miners to decide whether they wanted to accept a tx where the gas is paid in a non-ETH erc20 like OMG or BAT. IMO it's unlikely that a very large portion of gas will be paid in anything except ETH.